# variables added by a slider not transferring unless clicked inside textform?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

please see my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/rew6xjep/7/

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('bitcoin').onkeyup = function() {
    var bitcoin = (this.value);
    document.getElementById("btc-amount").innerHTML = "BTC amount requested: " +bitcoin;
    }
</script>
```

when you slide the slider I want the variable for bitcoin to update, but it updates only after I click the textbox and type in it or go to the next step and click edit from there and click get quote again...

Comment: Your fiddle works perfectly on my pc.

Comment: really? please pay attention if the BTC value transferred after you click getting the quote there. without typing into the box just using the slider.